# Group XML elements by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a variable named `filt` holding an xml like this:

```
<filters>
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Transparent" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Antal" FILTERNAME="10" UNITCODE="mapper" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Indpakning" FILTERNAME="Æske" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Materiale" FILTERNAME="PP" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Bredde" FILTERNAME="35.6" UNITCODE="cm" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="blue" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Dybde" FILTERNAME="5" UNITCODE="mm" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="red" UNITCODE="" />
</filters>
```

I want to group these elements by its 'FILTER' attribute.
That is I want an output xml like this (please note that xml elements are rearranged by filter atribute i.e. all elements with FILTER as farve is at adjacent position now)

```
<filters>
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Transparent" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="blue" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="red" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Antal" FILTERNAME="10" UNITCODE="mapper" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Indpakning" FILTERNAME="Æske" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Materiale" FILTERNAME="PP" UNITCODE="" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Bredde" FILTERNAME="35.6" UNITCODE="cm" />
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Dybde" FILTERNAME="5" UNITCODE="mm" />
</filters>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="grouped_filt" select="$filt//ISP_WebItem[@FILTER = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@FILTER ]"></xsl:variable>
```

but of no use. I am unable to find anything wrong in this. Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly do you want this to do?  The expression you have so far will select all `ISP_WebItem` elements whose `FILTER` attribute is the same as that of its immediately preceding sibling, i.e. if you have a run of elements with filter values v1, v1, v1, v2, v2, v3, v3 then it would select _all but the first_ of each group, and then take their `FILTER` attributes - you'd end up with a node set containing two `v1` attributes, one `v2` and one `v3`.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach to this in XSLT 1.0 is called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="itemByFilter" match="ISP_WebItem" use="@FILTER" />

  <xsl:template match="filters">
    <filters>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ISP_WebItem[
          generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)[1])]" />
    </filters>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ISP_WebItem">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)[1])` is a way to select just the *first* `ISP_WebItem` element with each `FILTER` value and apply the `ISP_WebItem` template to that element.  In the template we then copy *all* elements that have the same `FILTER` value.

Edit:

You say the `<filters>` element is in a "variable named filt" rather than being something you're matching directly from the input document.  In that case, you can use the same key definition

```
  <xsl:key name="itemByFilter" match="ISP_WebItem" use="@FILTER" />
```

but instead of `<xsl:template match="filters">` you use `<xsl:for-each select="$filt/filters">`.  If the `filt` variable is a result tree fragment rather than a node set - i.e. it was created as

```
<xsl:variable name="filt">
  <filters>
    <!-- ... -->
  </filters>
</xsl:variable>
```

the you will need an extension function to turn it back into a node set

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="itemByFilter" match="ISP_WebItem" use="@FILTER" />


  <xsl:variable name="filt">
    <filters>
      <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Transparent" UNITCODE="" />
      <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Antal" FILTERNAME="10" UNITCODE="mapper" />
      <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="blue" UNITCODE="" />
    </filters>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="grouped_filt">
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($filt)/filters">
      <filters>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ISP_WebItem[
            generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)[1])]" />
      </filters>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Demonstrate that the grouping did the right thing -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="$grouped_filt" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ISP_WebItem">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('itemByFilter', @FILTER)" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This style sheet, when run over any input document (e.g. `<foo/>`) will output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<filters>
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="Transparent" UNITCODE=""/>
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Farve" FILTERNAME="blue" UNITCODE=""/>
  <ISP_WebItem FILTER="Antal" FILTERNAME="10" UNITCODE="mapper"/>
</filters>
```